# Log4Net repository scoped properties

Tags: .net, log4net

I'm creating my log4net loggers programatically, by loading an xml file, and setting global properties, like...

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <!-- level is set programatically <level value="DEBUG" /> -->
    <appender-ref ref="Log4NetDefaultAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="Log4NetDefaultAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <param name="File" value="%property{workingDirectory}\..\\Logs\\%property{processName}.log" type="log4net.Util.PatternString"/>
```

And...

```
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["workingDirectory"] = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["processName"] = processName;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["sessionid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        XmlConfigurator.Configure("myconfig.xml");
```

I'm doing it this way because I have about 100 processes that need to log to individual files - I don't want to maintain 100 config files.  Dynamically creating the config is fine, but...

In some cases, I need to log to a secondary log file.  I want to use the same code and config, but open a separate log file.

I'm having problems because of the global nature of log4net.  Just creating a new instance closes the first log file, then continues writing the in the secondary.  I'm assuming this is because XmlConfigurator.Configure() is global.

I've tried creating a separate repository...

```
        ILoggerRepository logRepository = LogManager.CreateRepository(processName);
```

but that still has problems with the properties being global (I use these properties in the output too).

I tried setting the properties on the repository, but only the global properties are used.

```
logRepository.Properties["sessionid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

I'm also printing the "sessionid" in the log output using %property{sessionid}, but being global changing it on one logger changes it on the other.

Can this be done?  Am I using repositories incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Just some feedback on 100 files logging to one file is not very efficient. If you have a lot of log messages, the logging will probably have a huge impact on the performance of your solution. Every time a process logs the process tries to get a lock and releases the lock after logging. Think about an other appender for performance.

The on logging to your secondary file, I would create a second appender in your configuration and then specify the logger that uses that configuration.

```
<logger name="SecondFile">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>

var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SecondFile");
logger.Info("This logs to your second file");
```

On this page you can find how to work with the [log4net different contexts](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html). The different scopes are explained and I would suggest to have a look at stacks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  100 processes is more like 100 tasks that can run at any time, and log to their own file with the process name in the filename.  Unless I am mis-understanding contexts, I dont think that will work - the process uses 2 loggers, but will alway be in the same context - same global, same thread, same logical thread, same event.